# Blender Mantaflow 2.93

Tags: mantaflow

I've been told that Mantaflow is built into blender. So can you guys tell me where I could possibly find it? I've been needing for a project I'm working on.

Comment: Mantaflow is what Blender uses as its fluid simulation engine.  If you do a fluid simulation in Blender you are using Mantaflow.

Comment: Smoke also, Marty

Comment: Mantaflow is built into the physics tab, under fluid. You can look up tutorials online.

Comment: Fire also Marty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the blue orbit thing close to the modifiers tab. It's called "Physics Properties".

Here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QnjA.jpg

Then just select the type of simulation you want and mess with the parameters.